# how to combine Series with different date into one DataFrame

Tags: python, export-to-csv, quandl

I get some data from quandl and fred, and I try to make them into the same CSV file. But my `spot_price` data is missing in the csv file. 
Here's my code:

```
import quandl

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = "your key"
ice_b1=quandl.get("CHRIS/ICE_B1",start_date="2017-1-1")["Settle"]

from fredapi import Fred

fred = Fred(api_key='your key')
spot_price = fred.get_series('DCOILBRENTEU',observation_start='2017-01-01')

dic={"b1":ice_b1,"spot price":spot_price}
df =pd.DataFrame(data=dic)
df.to_csv('/Users/apple/Desktop/crude_oil.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

The spec for fredapi.get_series defines the required parameters (when specifying an observation_start) thus:

```
 Parameters
        ----------
        series_id : str
            Fred series id such as 'CPIAUCSL'
        observation_start : datetime or datetime-like str such as '7/1/2014', optional
            earliest observation date
        observation_end : datetime or datetime-like str such as '7/1/2014', optional
            latest observation date
        kwargs : additional parameters
            Any additional parameters supported by FRED. You can see https://api.stlouisfed.org/docs/fred/series_observations.html for the full list
```

It looks to me like your date format is wrong - try using

```
spot_price = fred.get_series('DCOILBRENTEU',observation_start='1/1/2017')
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really saved my day!!
Btw, do you know how to find the series index date by its value? For instance, if I wanna find the dates when spot_price is less than 60, then use those dates to check the price of ice_b1. How to do it?